# Помогите разобраться в БД SQLite в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Есть два вопроса:
1. Подчеркнуто красным в моей БД открытой в android studio. Почему, я не пойму. И как это исправить? Возможно из-за этого у меня падает приложение при нажати на кнопку.
2. Хотелось бы выводить текст из БД в поле под календарем, при нажатии на какой-то день, или автоматически если этот день настал (делаю церковный календарь). Но у меня нехватает знаний.
Теперь подробнее:
БД делаю в DB Browser (SQLite). Из нее делаю экспорт БД в файл SQLite, получается такой файл - info.db.sql.
Использовал информацию отсюда: 
http://blog.harrix.org/article/6610

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    TextView textView;

    private DataBaseHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDBHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        try {
            mDBHelper.updateDataBase();
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            throw new Error("UnableToUpdateDatabase");
        }

        try {
            mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            throw mSQLException;
        }

        //Найдем компоненты в XML разметке
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.celebration);

        //Пропишем обработчик клика кнопки
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String product = "";

                Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM clients", null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    product += cursor.getString(1) + " | ";
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
                cursor.close();

                textView.setText(product);
            }
        });


        CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year,
                                            int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                String selectedDate = String.valueOf (dayOfMonth) +
                        "." + (month + 1) + "." + year +
                        " ";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

class DataBaseHelper

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_NAME = "info.db.sql";
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;
    private boolean mNeedUpdate = false;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        else
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        this.mContext = context;

        copyDataBase();

        this.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    public void updateDataBase() throws IOException {
        if (mNeedUpdate) {
            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            if (dbFile.exists())
                dbFile.delete();

            copyDataBase();

            mNeedUpdate = false;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    private void copyDataBase() {
        if (!checkDataBase()) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try {
                copyDBFile();
            } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyDBFile() throws IOException {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        //InputStream mInput = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.info);
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0)
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            mNeedUpdate = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте сразу несколько разных вопросов.

Comment: Просто эти вопросы связаны между собой и относятся к одному типу - работа с Sqlite (создание, загрузка и обработка).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте я покажу вам примерно как сделать и запустить готовую `БД`:

Для этого нужно заюзать библитотеку `SQLiteAssetHelper`.

`implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'`

Она как раз и предназначена для того, что бы читать файл из `Assets` что как бы есть в ее названии.
Файл базы должен быть вот таким:

```
database.db
```

и мы кладем его в папку assets.

Далее создаем класс `MyDatabase` и расширяющемся  от `SQLiteAssetHelper`

```
class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String TAG = "TAG";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; 
private static String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
private final Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;


public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
    try {
        myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        try {
            clearDB();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            setForcedUpgrade();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "MyDatabase: " + e);
    }
}



public void closeDB() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    if (db != null && db.isOpen())
        db.close();
}





 public void clearDB() {
        if (myDataBase != null && myDataBase.isOpen()) {
            myDataBase.close();
        }
        File file = new File(context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath());
        SQLiteDatabase.deleteDatabase(file);
    }
```

ну и вот так можно получить все элементы :

```
//  ПОЛУЧИТЬ все элементы
public Cursor getAllData(String table_name) {
    myDataBase = getReadableDatabase();
    return myDataBase.query(table_name, null, null, null,
            null, null, null);
}
```

Значит выше что у нас происходит_ при первом запуске считывается база из папки assets, потом если мы поднимаем версию, она автоматически стирается и перезаписывается. Вот и все.

Теперь как работать с дынными:

Допустим во фрагменте
я обычно делаю инициализацию в классе `Application` не забудьте добавить в манифест.

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
private MyDatabase database;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    database = new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext());
}

public MyDatabase getDatabase() {
    return database;
}
```

}

А тут сам фрагмент:

```
private MyDatabase database;
database = new MyDatabase(getActivity());

if(getActivity()!= null){
        database = ((MyApplication)getActivity().getApplication()).getDatabase();
    }
```

и вот так примерно читаем:

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    retrieve();
                }
            });
        }


private void retrieve() {

    Cursor cursor = database.getAllData(TABLE);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        long _id = cursor.getLong(0);
        String number = cursor.getString(1);
        String station = cursor.getString(2);

//тут добавляем прочитанное

        List busList = new List(number, station);
        ItemList.add(busList);
    }


        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //и не забываем закрывать базу
    database.closeDB();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    database.closeDB();
}
```

В ВАШЕМ случае я бы создал отдельный класс и написал запрос к календарю, который бы возвращал текущую дату к примеру и использовал ее как ключ к колонкам, допустим примерно так:

```
public class TimeFormatter {
    private Calendar calendar;

    /** возвращает текущее время в таком формате: 2019-06-20 */
    public String getCurrentTimeMorning() {
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
        return simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
}
```

потом брал бы время из фрагменты так:

```
private String
        time_start;
private TimeFormatter timeFormatter = new TimeFormatter();

time_start = timeFormatter.getCurrentTimeMorning();
```

теперь у нас есть ключ-время.

Или получал бы его через `CalendarView`:

```
 //обработчик выбора даты
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, month, day);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
        time_start = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
//и тут можно сделать запрос на чтение:
        getMyData(time_start);
    }
};
```

Вот и все. Вам останется лишь самостоятельно написать запрос на выборку данных из таблицы и вывести эти данные. НАдеюсь чем то поможет. Будут вопросы - задавайте.

Comment: Если я использую свой файл info.db - то там внутри беспорядочный набор символов, так и должно быть?
Вроде все очень доходчиво обьяснили, буду пробовать. Спасибо огромное.

Comment: Внутрь него нужно смотреть с помощью браузера как бэ

Comment: А можно ли с вами связаться через почту или через skype? Я не могу все это в кучу сложить, я 3 месяца как учусь. Но очень, очень нужно. Пожалуйста.

Comment: Можно почему нет. Через почту, пожалуйста

Comment: Я не знаю вашего почтового адреса. Мой shesavid@gmail.com